# Find the occurrence of a datacell changing in an ordered dataset query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a sample dataset with the columns: Name/Mood/Date

```
Bob/Happy/11-11-20
Bob/Happy/11-12-20
Bob/Happy/11-13-20
Bob/Sad/11-14-20
Bob/Sad/11-15-20
Bob/Happy/11-16-20
Bob/Happy/11-17-20
Bob/Happy/11-18-20
```

How I would like the data to show is as follows:

```
Bob/:)/11-11-20
Bob/Happy/11-12-20
Bob/Happy/11-13-20
Bob/Sad/11-14-20
Bob/Sad/11-15-20
Bob/:)/11-16-20
Bob/Happy/11-17-20
Bob/Happy/11-18-20
```

Where the first occurrence of Bob being happy is replaced by a smile

So far, what I'm working with is:

```
SELECT 
    A.Name as 'Name',
    CASE WHEN A.Name = 'Happy' /*after not being 'Happy'*/ THEN ':)' <---THIS IS THE PART I'M HAVING PROBLEMS WITH
        ELSE A.Name END as 'Mood',
    A.Name as 'Date'
FROM TestTable A
ORDER BY A.Date ASC
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SSMS

Comment: @WesleyDaBes SSMS is not dbms. DBMS are Sql server, Oracle, etc. SSMS is editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use windowing functions, I assumed you want to do it for each person :

```
SELECT s.name
     , s.Mood
     , s.MoodDate
      , CASE WHEN (s.Mood <> ISNULL(LAG(Mood) OVER (partition BY NAME ORDER BY s.MoodDate),'First') AND s.Mood = 'Happy' )  THEN ':)' ELSE s.Mood END 
    FROM  TableName AS s
```